# How do you Authenticate a NestJS API to a Azure Industrial IoT Plattform?

Tags: authentication, azure-active-directory, authorization, nestjs, azure-iot-hub

My companys Services are a little bit complicated. Thats why my company demands that i write an NestJS API that requests the Data from the Azure Industrial IoT Services(those are APIs or hubs i dont realy know) for a particular job.

My problem now is, that i dont know how to authenticate nestjs to azure. So that i can request from those Azure Services the Data.

The structure of this project looks like this:

**AZURE - Services are behind**<--------->**NestJS-Api + Postgres**<---------->**AngularApp**

The nestJS-Api should have authorisation to request data 24/7(the whole time)

Comment: Have you gone through this for Azure IOT service authentication? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-security#authentication

Comment: @StanleyGong i did not. my company just told me to use passport.js. Which ist not realy working. I get a token from azure-ad but cannot request from those apis. But Thank you i will go through your link. :)

Comment: Welcome,if you want to manage Azure services such as create/delete an Azure IOT hub service, you will need to get an access token and call Azure management API. But if you already have an Azure IOT hub service, and you want to use this service by API, you can just refer to the link I provided above to call IOT services.Let me know if you have any more questions.

Comment: do you have any more questions? If not, may I summarize the answer above as an answer?

Comment: @StanleyGong im currently working on the API. And not on the Authentication. I will go through some time later. (im new so i dont know if i need to mark this question as answered. I dont even know if i can do it. So mark your answer as an answer)

Comment: Thanks for your reply Feridun, I have summarized the answer, if it is helpful,please click on the checkmark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in to accept it as an answer, so that it will help others and close this question. Feel free to let me know if you have any issue while you are coding with Azure : )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to manage Azure services such as create/delete an Azure IOT hub service, you will need to get an access token by `passport.js` and call [Azure management API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/iothub/).

But if you already have an Azure IOT hub service, you want to use this service by API, and you are facing the authentication issue, you can just refer to [this official guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-security#authentication).